# Internet Explorer issue: switching dynamic PHP generated image with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, background-image

So on my page I have a select menu that is modified by jQuery. Simply, jQuery takes the style attributes and appends them to a list.
Everything works fine except for the background-image, which is generated via PHP.
looks great in Chrome, which picks it all up, but IE/Safari don't show any image. It comes up as background-image:none;

The page is here:

http://stickeraddicts.com/index.php?_a=lettering-tool

And it is supposed to look like the gif on my homepage. Again, in Chrome things are perfect. The problem is IE mainly.

Anyway, here is the HTML for a list item

```
<option style="background-image:url(/letteringtool/fontpreview.php?txt=Alba%20Super&color=ffffff&font=/fonts/alba.ttf&width=200&height=25&padding=10);text-indent:-9999px;" value="alba">Alba Super</option>
```

And here is the jQuery that affects it (inside of jQtransform)

```
var oLi = $('<li style="border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); background-image:'+ $(this).css('backgroundImage')+';text-indent:'+$(this).css('text-indent')+';"><a href="#" index="'+ i +'">'+ $(this).html() +'</a></li>');
$ul.append(oLi);
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to tell us what is wrong. "don't work properly" isn't something we can answer. What is it doing, and what should it be doing?

Comment: sorry. The image doesn't show at all and when I look at the page, the image comes up as background-image:none

Comment: I noticed that the images show under compatibility mode for IE. Now i'm really confused

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: press F12 on IE to open the developer console, then check if css attributes be loaded correctly, for geral, IE need some extra attributes like display: block, height: 100%, some css tricks... try there